# What Is a Weighted Local Histogram?

Tags: image-processing, gaussian, statistics, histogram

I'm reading through a couple of academic papers, and this terms often comes up "local weighted histogram". An example of quote is the following:

> First, cumulative histograms are built for every pixel from its neighborhood, using Gaussian-neighborhood weighting

I would be able to construct a local histogram, I'm not sure what this weighting is about.

Say the central pixel is at $p_0 = (y_0,x_0)$, and we have two pixels of same gray scale value $r$ at coordinates $p_1 = (y_1,x_1)$ and $p_2 = (y_1,x_1)$, but such that $d(p_0,p_1) < d(p_0,p_2)$. A normal histogram would count that value $r$ twice. With a Gaussian weighting for example how would we count such pixel value in the histogram construction?

Answer (score 1):

A weighted local histogram would mean filtering the image $I(x,y)$ with a localised filter $H(x,y)$ (gaussian in this example). The resultant image is the 2D convolution $Y(x,y) = I(x,y)*H(x,y)$. The normal histogram of $Y(x,y)$ is the localised histogram of $I(x,y)$. It is used to view certain specific characteristics of an image depending on the filter used

Answer (score 0):

A precise explanation of the term **local histogram** is not possible unless someone specifies its mathematical definition. Yet the term **local** makes the following sense: compute a histogram from a bunch of spatially related pixels, instead of using the whole image.

In addition, the use of a **weight** further implies that (usually) the closer pixels will have a dominance on the computed histogram statistics. However, it's not clear how this weighting would be translated into the mechanics of the histogram computation.

Comment: By "local histogram" I mean fix a tile in your image and compute that histogram.

Comment: yes that's what I mean as local. What do you mean by **tile** here? a small square within the image or what?

Comment: yes. Small square region inside the image.

Comment: Hi: the paper may be referring to the histogrammed output of loess, a local smoothing procedure used in statistical applications.. I can't say for sure but it's possible.